# How can I convert the string of a JavaScript object literal to a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I convert the string...

```
"{ name: 'John' }"
```

...to an actual JavaScript object literal that will allow me to access the data using its keys (I.e. varname["name"] == "John")? I can't use JSON.parse(), since the string is invalid JSON.

Comment: I'd prefer avoiding `eval` and make the source produce proper JSON.

Comment: Starting with JSON is best, as @Thilo suggested. Parsing strings with `eval(…)`, `require(…)`, `new Function(…)`, `document.createElement('script')`, etc, will cause the code in the string to be executed, which is probably dangerous if the string comes from outside your program. If your only source of data is JS object literals, the best way may be to use an AST parser such as [Esprima](https://esprima.org/) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56649864/277303).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the previous question

```
s="{ name: 'John'}";
eval('x='+s);
```

Comment: Ahhh, now I see what you're saying. So sorry that was so difficult for me to understand. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Example with `new Function`

```js
var str = "{ name: 'John' }";
var fnc = new Function( "return " + str );
var obj = fnc();
console.log(obj.name);
```

Comment: @QuinnComendant new Function is evaluating it so not as safe as you think.

Comment: Yikes! You're correct: `var f = new Function("return " + "alert(1);"); f();` does execute alert(1). 

Comment: Weird you pick my answer to post that comment and the real solution is, return proper JSON.

Comment: Sorry, it just followed from learning `new Function` isn't safe. I've moved my comment to the OP's question. 

Answer (score 1):

You could use eval().

```
var str = "{ name: 'John' }";
var obj = eval("(" + str + ")");
```