# Converting JavaScript object literal to JavaScript object WITHOUT 'eval'

Tags: javascript

I'm making a web scraper, most of the data on the web page is in JavaScript object literal form, e.g.:

```
// Silly example
var user = {
    name: 'John', 
    surname: 'Doe',
    age: 21,
    family: [
        {
            name: 'Jane',
            surname: 'Doe',
            age: 37
        },
        // ...
    ]
};
```

So when I search for the contents in my JavaScript app the Object above would be:

```
"{name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age: 21, family: [{name: 'Jane', surname: 'Doe', age: 37}]}"
```

Is it possible to parse those to regular JavaScript Objects without using 'eval' or making my own parser? I saw other similar questions about this but the answers are not applicable: they all suggest `JSON.parse()` (not applicable) and `eval` (I can't use it for security reasons). [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171985/how-can-i-convert-the-string-of-a-javascript-object-literal-to-a-javascript-obje), for example, all the answers suggest `eval` or `new Function()` which are basically the same thing.

If there are no other ways would it be a viable option to convert the literal to proper JSON and then parse it to JavaScript object?

This is what I tried right now, it worked on a simple object but I'm not sure it will work everywhere:

```
const literal = script.innerText.slice(script.innerText.indexOf('{'), script.innerText.lastIndexOf('}') + 1);
const json = literal.replace(/.*:.*(\".*\"|\'.*\'|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|true|false|[0-9]+).*,/g, (prev) => {
  let parts = prev.split(':');
  let key = '"' + parts.shift().trim() + '"';
  let value = parts.join(':').replace(/'.*'/, (a) => {
    return '"' + a.slice(1, a.length - 1) + '"';
  }).trim();
  return key + ':' + value;
});
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: An object literal is a JS object. If you need a JSON string, then see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: @Teemu but based on the statement that OP is using a web scraper, I'd assume that he has it in string format. I'd be interested in why it isn't possible to use JSON.parse

Comment: if it is in a file, you can load JS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js

Comment: Is this between script tags in a HTML document, or an included file?

Comment: You could use JavaScript parser like [esprima](http://esprima.org/) or [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn)

Comment: @TomM It looks like I'm not reading enough the question nowadays. Yes, the provided example is most likely a string, but it is not a JSON string, that's why JSON.parse can't parse it.

Comment: @TomM  `I'd be interested in why it isn't possible to use JSON.parse` Because even if you take away `var user =` and the trailing `;`, its not valid JSON. eg.. `{hello: 'there'}` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @TomM `JSON.parse()` is not usable beacuse the Object literal shown is valid JavaScript but not valid JSON

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev could you post an example of how you are currently trying to consume the string inside your app?

Comment: @Lewis between scripts tag, the problem is not extracting the object string but parsing it to a JavaScript variable

Comment: So your option is to write a parser or write code to convert it to valid JSON.

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev Fair enough, knowing that gives us some context though.

Comment: Obligatory note that parsing strings with `eval(…)`, `require(…)`, `new Function(…)`, `document.createElement('script')`, et al, will cause the code in the string to be executed, which is probably dangerous if the string comes from outside your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use node, an easy workaround would be

```
// scraper.js
const fs = require('fs');
const objectString = myScraper.scrape('example.com');

fs.writeFileSync('./scraped.js', objectString);

// myAppUsingTheData.js
const myObj = require('myAppUsingTheData');
```

However, require still involves evaluation in some way. AND you'd need separate processes in order to access your object. Also, you'd need to somehow insert `module.exports`. If you want to parse Objects only, try [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5)

```
const myObj = JSON5.parse(objectString);
console.log(myObj.name)
```

Using JSON5 will effectively prevent you from running malicious code that is not an object in your app and apparently can parse unquoted JSON keys.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple demo how you can use `esprima` to get globally declared variables

```js
"use strict";

const src = `
var user = {
 name: 'John',
 surname: 'Doe',
 age: 21,
 family: [
  {
   name: 'Jane',
   surname: 'Doe',
   age: 37
  },
  // ...
 ]
};`;
const src2 = `
var a = [1,2,3], b = true;
var s = "some string";
var o = {a:1}, n = null;
var some = {'realy strange' : {"object":"'literal'"}}
`;

function get_globals(src) {
  return esprima.parse(src).body
    .filter(({type}) => type === "VariableDeclaration") // keep only variables declarations
    .map(({declarations}) => declarations)
    .flat()
    .filter(({type}) => type === "VariableDeclarator")
    .reduce((vars, {id: {name}, init}) => {
      vars[name] = parse(init);
      return vars;
    }, {});
}

console.log(get_globals(src));
console.log(get_globals(src2));

/**
 * Parse expression
 * @param expression
 * @returns {*}
 */
function parse(expression) {
  switch (expression.type) {
    case "ObjectExpression":
      return ObjectExpression(expression);
    case "Identifier":
      return expression.name;
    case "Literal":
      return expression.value;
    case "ArrayExpression":
      return ArrayExpression(expression);
  }
}

/**
 * Parse object expresion
 * @param expression
 * @returns {object}
 */
function ObjectExpression(expression) {
  return expression.properties.reduce((obj, {key, value}) => ({
    ...obj,
    [parse(key)]: parse(value)
  }), {});
}

/**
 * Parse array expression
 * @param expression
 * @returns {*[]}
 */
function ArrayExpression(expression) {
  return expression.elements.map((exp) => parse(exp));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/esprima@~4.0/dist/esprima.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For data like this you could might be able to use a couple of regex's to convert into a valid JSON object.

Below is an example..

ps. It might not be 100% foolproof for all object literals.

```js
var str = "{name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age: 21, family: [{name: 'Jane', surname: 'Doe', age: 37}]}";

var jstr = str
  .replace(/\'(.*?)\'/g, '"$1"')
  .replace(/([\{ ]*?)([a-z]*?)(\:)/gi, '$1"$2"$3');

var obj = JSON.parse(jstr);

console.log(obj);
```

As pointed out by @ponury-kostek, and by myself using regEx can be limited.
Using some sort of AST parsing like Esprima is certainly a good idea, especially if your already using an AST parser.

But if an AST parser is overkill, a more robust version below using Javascript might be better.  Ps. again it might not be 100% correct, but it should cope with the majority of Object literals.

```js
var str = `{
  name: 'John:', surname: 'Doe', age: 21,
  family: [
    {name: 'Jane\\n\\r', surname: 'Doe', age: 37},
    {'realy:strange indeed' : {"object":"'\\"literal'"}}
  ]
}`;


const objLits = [...':0123456789, \t[]{}\r\n'];

function objParse(src) {
  const input = [...src];
  const output = [];
  let inQ = false, inDQ = false, 
    inEsc = false, inVname = false;
  for (const i of input) {
    if (inEsc) {
      inEsc = false;    
      output.push(i);
    } else if (i === "\\") {
      inEsc = true;
      output.push(i);
    } else if (i === "'" && !inDQ) {
      output.push('"');
      inQ = !inQ;
    } else if (i === '"' && !inQ) {
      output.push('"');
      inDQ = !inDQ;      
    } else if (!inVname & !inQ & !inDQ & !inEsc) {
      if (objLits.includes(i)) {
        output.push(i);
      } else {
        inVname = true;
        output.push('"');
        output.push(i);
      }
    } else if (inVname) {
      if (i === ':') {
        inVname = false;
        output.push('"');
      }
      output.push(i);
    } else {
      output.push(i);
    }
  }
  const ostr = output.join('');
  return JSON.parse(ostr);
}

console.log(objParse(str));
```

Comment: This will crash if you use quoted keys or if you use quotes in values (escaped), try to parse something like `var some = {'realy strange' : {"object":"'literal'"}}`

Comment: @ponury-kostek  Yes, I did mention it wouldn't be 100%.. I've updated with a JS version that should be a bit more robust.  PS.  I use AST parser's too, and I think that's the most robust way of doing this.   But for something quick and dirty I'll leave these version here.

Comment: OP had mention that he is making web scraper, that's why I suggested using some JS parser

Answer (score -1):

A script tag can be added with the script text :

```js
var JS = `var user = {
    name: 'John', 
    surname: 'Doe',
    age: 21,
    family: [
        {
            name: 'Jane',
            surname: 'Doe',
            age: 37
        },
    ]
};`;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = JS
document.head.appendChild(script);

console.log( user )
```

Comment: This has the same issue as eval() does, anybody can put any code they want in the text.